# Would a macroscopic sphere with the thicknesss of a few atoms behave as an artificial atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, nanoscience

As quantum dots are composed of closely packed atoms, where their electronic levels are bound and in a confined system, would a similar system, with the same thickness as a quantum dot but much larger surface area still display the properties associated with quantum dots?

Comment: That is not a good description of a quantum dot.

Comment: What is lacking then? In either case, I believe the question is clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a [quantum well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_well). This is a kind of heterostructure where the confinement is only in one direction, while the others are translationally invariant as in the bulk crystal.

The properties of quantum wells are very different from those of quantum dots: although you'll get some energy quantization, instead of single levels you'll get discrete sets of 2D bands. Density of states of a quantum well is also [qualitatively different](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/book/chapter2/ch2_4.htm) from those of quantum dots and bulk crystals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Be it that this system I describe is a quantum well, would it still display the confinement you describe, despite it’s surface area being macroscopic in size?

Comment: @Evamentality well, I have described an actually existing kind of heterostructure that's extensively used in modern LEDs and lasers. Yes it does display the confinement, and in particular, it's evident in absorption spectrum for light polarized in the direction of confinement (TE mode).